# Excluding traffic via IP Filter in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase-analytics

I'd like to filter out my own traffic from analytics in firebase using my IP address.  I don't see any way to do it.

The filter shown on the analytics dashboard has no option for IP Addresses.
Additionally, when I enter my Google Analytics account & property for the project it doesn't allow adding any filters.

[image: firebase analytics filters (no option for IP address)]

[image: no filters for App + web properties on Google analytics]

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that this is not possible (for now) in firebase analytics.  I've reverted to using google analytics for the time being due to numerous features/functionality missing on the firebase version.

Comment: Hey Gabe, I also need this filter. Which other features did you find out that weren't working? I'm not able to see some of my data in Real Time and I'm starting to think that this might be related to the fact that I'm using a Firebase Analytics account. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944747/firebase-google-analytics-console-weird-behavior-events-are-logged-but-dont-sh). I'm also thinking about moving to Google Analytics directly. Thanks!

Comment: tbh I haven't used the user snapshot functionality at all so I'm not sure if that works better on GA.  There are much more granular demographic breakdowns on Google Analytics.  You can use both at the same time to compare their feature sets (just use 2 tags)