# Firebase Google Analytics Console weird behavior. Events are logged but don't show up on User Snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, gtag.js

I'm using Firebase Analytics and I'm still exploring the Google Analytics Console.

I think there's something wrong with my data, or the way I'm logging it. I have a Single Page App built with React + Firebase.

Since my app is all client side routes, for every page that it renders, I'm firing the following effect to log the `screen_view` event:

```
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.analytics().logEvent("screen_view", {
    screen_name: window.location.pathname,
    page_title: "My Page Title"
  });
},[firebase]);
```

So far, so good. It runs without any errors, and it seems to be logging the event (or at least, I can see the events in some parts of the console).

**Here is the test I did that came back with weird results.**

Note: I'm monitoring through the Realtime tab over on Google Analytics Console.

[image]

I accessed my website, and click on 5 different links. After each page loaded, the `screen_view` event was fired and I could see this number for total events going from 20 to 25. I.e: my effects were fired and my events were logged!

[image]

When you click on "Trending" you open up a window with the count per event type in the last minutes, and I could see the `screen_view` events going from 12 to 17, which is all correct, so far.

[image]

But since this is a new website and I'm currently the only user, I was able to click on "View user snapshot" and see my own activity in the report, and it's supposed to be in real time.

[image]

But the weird thing is that my `screen_view` events don't show up in the snapshot AT ALL. Not on real time and it's not a delay issue. They just don't appear in my user activity.

[image]

**QUESTION**

What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong? Weren't my events supposed to appear in my user's snapshot timeline on Real Time (or even with some delay)? This is getting really difficult to learn and test if I can't see the results of my code logged on screen.

Is there a better way to test this? I mean, I need to update my code and be able to see the changes in the events a user triggers.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm puzzled by that same view, my guess is that the events has not been sent/collected yet but then what's the purpose of having that view...?

Comment: @lelloman sorry.. I didn't. I went back to `gtag` and I'm not using Firebase Analytics anymore.. That was my "solution" to this. So far, `gtag` is doing the job really well and I feel that I'm more in control of it.